# Can't add image to button in HeroCard

Tags: c#, botframework

I'm trying to add an image/icon on a button in HeroCard, but for some reason it doesn't work.
Any idea what could be the problem?

```
var logo= @"https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/89/Farm-Fresh_user_zorro.png";
var button= new CardAction("openUrl", value: "someUrl", image: logo);

var card = new HeroCard
{
    Title = "title",
    Subtitle = "some SubTitle",
    Text = "Some Text",
    Buttons = new List<CardAction>()
    {
        button
    }
};
```

Comment: You should provide more information than _it doesn't work_. Like, _in what way_ doesn't it work? What happens when you run the code? And other information like that.

Comment: What channel does it not work on? Have you tried other channels? Does it work in the emulator?

Answer (score 0):

> trying to add an image/icon on a button in HeroCard, but for some reason it doesn't work.

In [Bot Builder for .NET documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/d3/d1f/class_microsoft_1_1_bot_1_1_connector_1_1_card_action.html#a7e63c00ae4c8f68cd0ba9e3bb58155fa), we can find:

> "*URL Picture which will appear on the button, next to text label.*"

In [Bot Builder for Node.js documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat-reference/classes/_botbuilder_d_.cardaction.html#image), we can find:

> "*For buttons an image to include next to the buttons label. **Not supported by all channels.***"

But based on my experience and [this github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2232), it seems that it does not be implemented in any channel.